# How long will it take for the German and Japanese private betas to start?

Tags: support, area-51, private-beta

In the past couple of days both the German and Japanese proposals in area51 reached 100% committed and display the message "We are preparing for its launch and expect to create it soon."

How long does it usuall take from the time 100% is reached until the beginning of the private beta?

(I'm about to embark on a long trip so may well miss it.)

**UPDATE**

I've just noticed that the German one has entered a sub-phase that the Japanese one hasn't got to yet where it has the beta tab and states that it will start in 7 days. It's the length of time between hitting 100% and making this "7 days" announcement I was interested in.

Comment: btw we need one more language proposal to complete the axis power revival to take over the world :P

Comment: I found myself needing a Korean Language & Usage site about an hour ago (-:

Comment: There is already proposal on that ;) .. I wonder when will the Japanese beta start. I've already prepared >10 questions to be asked there ...

Comment: I'll be hitchhiking in Japan in a few days so I'm sure it will be very timely (-:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We're launching the German site's beta first, to work out the kinks - this is the first explicitly multi-lingual site in the network, so there are bound to be a few unexpected issues...

The Japanese site beta will launch once the German site has settled in a bit.

Comment: I bet @balpha is aiming for world domination before the Japanese will ;-)

Comment: I hope the multi-lingual site allows me to write questions & answers in both the target language and english separately so that people can switch from the language to english version. That's be totally cool. But I'd be content with just the normal SE architecture nevertheless.